# Problems with 2 D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

I wrote the following code in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int  main()
{
  int a[10][10]={1};
  //------------------------
  printf("%d\n",&a);
  printf("%d\n",a);
  printf("%d\n",*a);
  //-------------------------
  printf("%d",**a);

  return 0;
}
```

With the above 3 printf statements I got the same value. On my machine it's 2686384. But with the last statement I got 1.

Isn't it something going wrong? These statements mean:

1. The address of `a` is 2686384
2. The value stored in `a` is 2686384
3. the value that is stored at address of variable pointed by `a` (i.e. at 2686384) is 2686384.

This means `a` must be something like a variable pointing towards itself...

Then why is the output of `*(*a)` 1? Why isn't it evaluated as `*(*a)=*(2686384)=2686384`?

Comment: Try this link and undersatnd basic of 2D array..

[dreferencing 2 d array] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923214/dreferencing-2-d-array?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int  main()
{
  // a[row][col]
  int a[2][2]={ {9, 2}, {3, 4} };
  // in C, multidimensional arrays are really one dimensional, but
  // syntax alows us to access it as a two dimensional (like here).

  //------------------------
  printf("&a            = %d\n",&a);
  printf("a             = %d\n",a);
  printf("*a            = %d\n",*a);
  //-------------------------

  // Thing to have in mind here, that may be confusing is:
  // since we can access array values through 2 dimensions,
  // we need 2 stars(asterisk), right? Right.

  // So as a consistency in this aproach,
  // even if we are asking for first value,
  // we have to use 2 dimensional (we have a 2D array)
  // access syntax - 2 stars.

  printf("**a           = %d\n", **a );         // this says a[0][0] or *(*(a+0)+0)
  printf("**(a+1)       = %d\n", **(a+1) );     // a[1][0] or *(*(a+1)+0)
  printf("*(*(a+1)+1)   = %d\n", *(*(a+1)+1) ); // a[1][1] or *(*(a+1)+1)
  // a[1] gives us the value on that position,
  // since that value is pointer, &a[i] returns a pointer value
  printf("&a[1]         = %d\n", &a[1]);
  // When we add int to a pointer (eg. a+1),
  // really we are adding the lenth of a type
  // to which pointer is directing - here we go to the next element in an array.

  // In C, you can manipulate array variables practically like pointers.
  // Example: littleFunction(int [] arr) accepts pointers to int, and it works vice versa,
  //          littleFunction(int* arr) accepts array of int.

  int b = 8;
  printf("b             = %d\n", *&b);

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An expression consisting the the name of an array can *decay* to a pointer to the first element of the array. So even though `a` has type `int[10][10]`, it can decay to `int(*)[10]`.

Now, this decay happens in the expression `*a`. Consequently the expression has type `int[10]`. Repeating the same logic, this again decays to `int*`, and so `**a` is an `int`, which is moreover the first element of the first element of the array `a`, i.e. `1`.

The other three print statements print out the *address* of, respectively, the array, the first element of the array, and the first element of the first element of the array (which are of course all the same address, just different types).

Comment: The ques here is how a, and *a share the same memory location as **a.

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena: They don't. Rather, `&a`, `a`, `*a` and have the same numeric *value*, which represents the location of `**a`. The reason is the same by which "Trafalgar Square", "London" and "Britain" are all correct descriptions of my current location.

Answer (score 1):

First, a word on arrays...

Except when it is the operand0 of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

The expression `&a` has type "pointer to 10-element array of 10-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[10][10]`.  The expression `a` has type "10-element array of 10-element array of `int`", which by the rule above decays to "pointer to 10-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[10]`.  And finally, the expression `*a` (which is equivalent to `a[0]`) has type "10-element array of `int`", which again by the rule above decays to "pointer to `int`".

*All three expressions have the same value* because the address of an array and the address of its first element are the same: `&a[0][0]` == `a[0]` == `*a` == `a` == `&a`.  However, the *types* of the expressions are different, which matters when doing pointer arithmetic.  For example, if I have the following declarations:

```
int (*ap0)[10][10] = &a;
int (*ap1)[10]     =  a;
int *ip            = *a;
```

then `ap0++` would advance `ap0` to point to the next 10x10 array of `int`, `ap1++` would advance `ap1` to pointer to the next 10-element array of `int` (or `a[1]`), and `ip++` would advance `ip` to point to the next `int` (`&a[0][1]`).

`**a` is equivalent to `*a[0]` which is equivalent to `a[0][0]`. which is the *value* of the first element of `a` and has type `int` and the value `1` (note that *only* `a[0][0]` is initialized to `1`; all remaining elements are initialized to `0`).

Note that you should use `%p` to print out pointer values:

```
printf("&a = %p\n", &a);
printf(" a = %p\n",  a);
printf("*a = %p\n", *a);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to print out pointer values, use `%p` - if you're on a 64 bit machine int almost certainly is smaller than a pointer.

`**a` is double dereferencing what's effectively a `int**`, so you end up with what the first element of the first sub-array is: 1.

Comment: But y *a, a give the same value...??

Answer (score 0):

If you define `a` as `T a[10]` (where `T` is some typedef), then a simple unadorned `a` means *the address of the start of the array*, the same as `&a[0]`. They both have type `T*`.

`&a` is also the address of the start of the array, but it has type `T**`.

Things become trickier in the presence of multi-dimensional arrays. To see what is happening, it is easier to break things down into smaller chunks using typedefs. So, you effectively wrote

```
typedef int array10[10];
array10 a[10];
```

[Exercise to reader: What is the type of `a`? (it is *not* `int**`)]

`**a` correctly evaluates to the first `int` in the array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

**From C99 Std**

Consider the array object defined by the declaration

```
int x[3][5];
```

Here x is a 3 × 5 array of ints; more precisely, x is an array of three element objects, each of which is an array of five ints. In the expression x[i], which is equivalent to (*((x)+(i))), **x is first converted to a pointer to the initial array of five ints**. Then i is adjusted according to the type of x, which conceptually entails multiplying i by the size of the object to which the pointer points, namely an array of five int objects. The results are added and indirection is applied to yield an array of five ints. When used in the expression x[i][j], that array is in turn converted to a pointer to the first of the ints, so x[i][j] yields an int.

so,

Initial array will be x[0][0] only.

all x, &x and *x will be pointing to x[0][0].

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing wrong with your code. Just they way you are thinking about it... The more I think about it the harder I realize this is to explain, so before I go in to this, keep these points in mind:

1. **arrays are not pointers**, don't think of them that way, they are different types.
2. the [] is an operator. It's a shift and deference operator, so when I write `printf("%d",array[3]);` I am shifting and deferencing

So an array (lets think about 1 dimension to start) is somewhere in memory:

```
int arr[10] = {1};
//Some where in memory---> 0x80001f23
                            [1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1]
```

So if I say:

```
*arr; //this gives the value 1
```

Why? because it's the same as `arr[0]` it gives us the value at the address which is the start of the array. This implies that:

```
arr; // this is the address of the start of the array
```

So what does this give us?

```
&arr; //this will give us the address of the array. 
      //which IS the address of the start of the array
      //this is where arrays and pointers really show some difference
```

So `arr == &arr;`. The "job" of an array is to hold data, the array will not "point" to anything else, because it's holding its own data. Period. A pointer on the other hand has the job to point to something else:

```
int *z;     //the pointer holds the address of someone else's values
z = arr;    //the pointer holds the address of the array
z != &z;    //the pointer's address is a unique value telling us where the pointer resides
            //the pointer's value is the address of the array
```

**EDIT:**
One more way to think about this:

```
int b;   //this is integer type
&b;      //this is the address of the int b, right?

int c[]; //this is the array of ints
&c;      //this would be the address of the array, right?
```

So that's pretty understandable how about this:

```
*c;   //that's the first element in the array
```

What does that line of code tell you? if I deference `c`, then I get an int. That means just plain `c` is an address. Since it's the start of the array it's the address of the array, thus:

```
c == &c;
```

Comment: This is wht my problem is..??
arr==&arr how is tht possible..??
how can u allow a pointer to store its own memory address and then dereference it to multiple times and say tht thts the value stored at a[0].

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena - You're not listening to point 1. arr IS NOT A POINTER. An array != a pointer. End of story. Take a look at my edit. Does that help? I think that might be clearer.

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena Keep in mind, the deference operator (*) is not something specific to pointers. It is an operator that works on memory addresses. I could do this: `int x = 0;` and then `printf("%d",*(&x));`, it would be pretty pointless, but that would work to print 0 and `x` is not a pointer